# What are the steps to get from $\frac{\sqrt{a+h-4} - \sqrt{a-4}}{h}$ to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+h-4} + \sqrt{a-4}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Evidently the following is true.
$$\frac{\sqrt{a+h-4} - \sqrt{a-4}}{h} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{a+h-4} + \sqrt{a-4}}$$

What are the steps to get from $\frac{\sqrt{a+h-4} - \sqrt{a-4}}{h}$ to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+h-4} + \sqrt{a-4}}$?  I am trying to refresh my math after not working on it for years and I am simply not seeing how this works.

Comment: Divide one by the other and simplify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Multiply the top and bottom by the conjugate of the numerator. Then simplify and cancel $h$. Remember the difference of squares.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

$$\frac{\sqrt{a+h-4} - \sqrt{a-4}}{h}\color{blue}{\frac{\sqrt{a+h-4} + \sqrt{a-4}}{\sqrt{a+h-4} + \sqrt{a-4}}}$$

And now in the numerator, use: $(x-y)(x+y) = x^2-y^2$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

start with the right expression and use:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt a + \sqrt b} = \frac{\sqrt a - \sqrt b}{\sqrt a - \sqrt b}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt a + \sqrt b}$$